# how can I simplify these pair of equations (2 variable equations) to eliminate one of the variables?

Tags: systems-of-equations

[image]

How can I simplify these equations to eliminate one of the variables?

$$0.5 = \dfrac{xe^{0.7(1-x)^2}75v}{60} + x(1-v)\\
0.5 = \dfrac{(1-x)e^{0.7x^2}35v}{60} + (1-x)(1-v)$$

Comment: $x$ is for product?

Comment: the variable are $x_1$, $v$, $x$?

Comment: 0.5 = (x*e^(0.7*(1-x)^2)*75*v)/60 + x*(1-v), 0.5 = ((1-x)*e^(0.7*(x)^2)*35*v)/60 + (1-x)*(1-v)

Comment: these are equations

Comment: @LuckyS yeah x is for product

Comment: The first equation looks like the best candidate to express $v$ as a function of $x$: expand the right-most thing in the RHS, move the part with no $v$ to the LHS, then factor $v$ out in the RHS, and you have it. Next step is to substitute $v$ in the second equation.

Comment: @user3733558  yeah thnx